# Unity GameOver Screen

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am just trying to activate game over screen when the Player's activate is 'false'. There is no animation, just the

There are 3 objects that need to be active and i added the script to those 3 objects but the screen does not appear.

How can i fix?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameOverManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject _player;

    void Start()
    {
        _player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (_player.activeInHierarchy == false)
        {
            gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }

        else
        {
            gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suspicion is the following. Whenever a Gameobject is not enabled, its code does not run. Test this by adding a Debug.Log("test") message.

If no message appears you can be certain that this check is never evaluated. To work around this simply add a script that is bound to an active gameObject. Creat a new empty gameobject in the scene. And add something like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameOverManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject _player;
    public GameObject _endscreen;

    void Update()
    {
        if (_player.activeInHierarchy == false)
        {
            _endscreen.SetActive(true);
        }

        else
        {
            _endscreen.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Assign the Variables in the Inspector by dragging the object to the empty fields. Never use GameObject.Find Methods.

If you need any further help tell me :)

Comment: Yes, it worked thank you buddy! But did not understand why we need another game object to arrange this event rather than simply creating a script and putting on the objects that we need to get relation with.

Comment: @naakal because if the gameobject is not active the script of the object is not active and it will not run. You can also activate/deactivate just the renderer (for images the Image component for example) to be able to do everything in the same gameobject.

Answer (score 0):

What you're currently doing is to find a single GameObject and checking whether that is active or not.

It would make more sense, and be more optimized, if each player object adds himself to a list of all players when he spawns. You can then loop over that list instead to check all players.

An even better way would be if you only call that "GameOver" check after a player has died. So when you call whichever method kills him.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Franz Answer, I did some modification in the code. You won't need any if else statement if you use a shortcut.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameOverManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject _player;
    public GameObject _endscreen;

    void Update()
    {
    _endscreen.SetActive(!_player.activeInHierarchy);
    }
}
```